# Can't install ggplot

Tags: python

I'm an experienced R user and i'm trying Python for the first time and i'm having a bad time trying to install packages. I guess there's an issue installing dependency {scipy} but i'm not sure how to solve it.

I'm on Windows 10 64bits and with VScode.

```
(env) PS C:\Users\alber\Documents\Python\Titanic> pip install ggplot
Collecting ggplot
  Using cached ggplot-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
Collecting brewer2mpl
  Using cached brewer2mpl-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting statsmodels
  Using cached statsmodels-0.12.0.tar.gz (17.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\alber\documents\python\titanic\env\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\alber\documents\python\titanic\env\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\alber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lcv198y3\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.29.14' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"'' 'scipy>=1.2'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (198 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting cython>=0.29.14
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.5
    Using cached numpy-1.17.5.zip (6.4 MB)
  Collecting scipy>=1.2
    Using cached scipy-1.5.3.tar.gz (25.2 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: still running...
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\alber\documents\python\titanic\env\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\alber\documents\python\titanic\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\alber\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplq20vzv8'
           cwd: C:\Users\alber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xazfjpx9\scipy
      Complete output (171 lines):
      setup.py:460: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\Users\alber\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-a1axib6x'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates      
        warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
      Running from SciPy source directory.
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\alber\\documents\\python\\titanic\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\alber\\documents\\python\\titanic\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

    ...
```

And a lot more that SO won't let me paste.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Numpy needs to be installed with scipy. Not exactly the answer but a workaround way to install all of the scientific tools for python would be installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) which comes prepackaged with the tools you'll need. You'll love playing around with Jupyter Notebook if you haven't already